# Forward UNIX syslog to Windows Event viewer

Tags: logging, windows, syslog, pfsense

I'm running a pfSense firewall which runs syslog and can forward it's logs to a remote syslog server. I'd like to be able to view these on my SBS 2011 server's event viewer, via a subscription. I assume there has to be some middleware which translates syslog messages to windows events, but I cannot find such a program.

There are lots of programs for sending windows events to a unix syslog server, but that is the opposite of what I want...

Comment: I'm a little curious why you'd want this.  Pure text events wouldn't translate well into MS event viewer's format.

Comment: I am guessing the ability to easily parse one log source.

Comment: As @alharaka says, I'd like to have one place to review the current status of my systems, rather than going through half a dozen different web interfaces. Since I can use the event viewer to collect data from client windows computers, server RAID arrays etc, I thought it'd be a piece of cake to add the firewall also

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool that will accept syslog messages and put them in a custom event log.  Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Syslogd.aspx). i have not used it but it looks promising.

Comment: Neat stuff.  God I love that website. When I am looking for something really obscure, I find such cool articles there. Haha.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, this will not be so productive in my mind's eye, so take that with a grain of salt.  Only you know why the tool fits the job.

Off the top of my head, no such tool exists.  Would you be comfortable with opening the Syslog server to some sort of remote access for the SBS server?  If so, you could probably script this yourself by parsing the file with cron'ed local copies over the SBS server or more easily by sharing it over a properly secured SMB-CIFS mount.  You would then write a wrapper script in the language of your choice to something like [eventcreate](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-5487-windows-xp-includes-the-eventcreate-utility-for-creating-custom-events-), which I have played with briefly, to get this done.  It would be extensible and be very DRY so you could mod it to different types of nail-looking problems in search of a hammer.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions using windows to easily receive and store UNIX/Linux syslog messages.  If you want to go that approach, one freeware approach is to install the necessary portions of cygwin and install its syslog server (which installs as a windows service).

Answer (score -1):

Windows Event Viewer or Windows Event Collector cannot natively accept syslog messages.  it requires a third party tool.

Comment: I'm not clear on why this is being downvoted.  I spent hours trying to figure out how to get Windows to natively accept syslog messages until I finally figured out that it couldn't.  Seeing an answer like this would have helped me significantly.