# Can I collect Syslog events in the Windows Event Collector?

Tags: logging, syslog, windows-event-log

I have a couple of *nix based systems that I'd like to start collecting logging information for. Is there a way to forward Syslog events to a Widnows server running the Windows Event Collector service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on [Forward UNIX syslog to Windows Event viewer](https://serverfault.com/questions/278369/forward-unix-syslog-to-windows-event-viewer) and the answer is that the application in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18086/Syslog-daemon-for-Windows-Eventlog can do that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how I missed that when I searched.